# Explicación del número mayor de los tres

Tags: java

es un código que hice para determinar cuál de los tres números que ingrese el usuario sea el mayor.

```
package repasos;


import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class rep_act2 {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        
    Scanner read = new Scanner(System.in);
    
    int[] numbers = {0,0,0};
    int index = 0;
    
    while (index<numbers.length) {
        System.out.println("Ingrese los números");
        int num = read.nextInt();
        
        boolean accept = true;
        
        for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
            if (numbers[i] == num)  {
                
                accept = false;
                
                System.out.println("El número "+num+" ya está en la lista, ingrese otro.");
            }
        }
        if (accept) {
            numbers[index] = num;
            index++;
        }
    }
    
    read.close();
    
    System.out.println("Digitación finalizada. Los números que ha introducido son: ");
    for (int num: numbers) {
        System.out.println("-. "+num);
        
    }
        if (numbers[0]>numbers[1]) {
            System.out.println("El número mayor es: "+numbers[0]);
        } else {
            if (numbers[1]>numbers[2]) {
                System.out.println("El número mayor es: "+numbers[1]);
            } else {
                    System.out.println("El número mayor es: "+numbers[2]);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Desearía que me puedan explicar para qué funcionan estas secciones de código, no supe exactamente que tuve que hacer pero tengo dudas con esto:

```
boolean accept = true;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == num)  {
            
            accept = false;
```

También aquí:

```
if (accept) {
        numbers[index] = num;
        index++;
```

Comment: Osea, acabas de hacer un código y no tienes ni idea de qué hace? Entonces... cómo lo hiciste? Qué querías hacer? *Qué querías que hiciese el código?* Porque si funciona, eso justo hace...

Comment: suena raro.. pero lo que estas preguntando suena mas raro.. tenes un iterador, un comparador.. que parte no entendiste de lo que hace? es que no hay nada raro ahi...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La primera seccion:

```
    boolean accept = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++) {
        if (numbers[i] == num)  {
            accept = false;
            System.out.println("El número "+num+" ya está en la lista, ingrese otro.");
        }
    }
```

Se compara el valor que contiene `num` con los valores que tiene el arreglo en ese momento, si `num` ya se encuentra en el arreglo, es cuando se cumple la condicion del `if`, y accept pasa a ser `false`.

La segunda seccion:

```
if (accept) {
            numbers[index] = num;
            index++;
        }
```

Esta directamente relacionada con la primera, si `num` no se encuentra en el arreglo, accept permanece como verdadero, cumpliendose la condicion `if (accept)`, entrando en el `if`, donde se almacena `num` en la posicion actual de index `numbers[index] = num;`, ademas se incrementa el valor de `index` para ingresar el siguiente valor. En caso contrario, cuando num se encuentra en el arreglo, accept cambia a `false`, saltandose la condicion, por lo que no se ingresaria ningun valor al arreglo, ni se incrementaria el index, entonces se repetiria el ciclo hasta ingresar un numero que el arreglo no contenga, y asi sucesivamente hasta llenar el arreglo.